# Left and right subclass decomposition of $G=\mathbb{Z}, H=4 \mathbb{Z}$ and $G=\mathscr{S}_{3}, H=$ $\{(1),(12)\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Find the left and right subclass decomposition for the following
> groups and subgroups and state the index: a) $G=\mathbb{Z}, H=4
> > \mathbb{Z}$, b) $G=\mathscr{S}_{3}, H=$ $\{(1),(12)\}$.

I'm not quite sure whether I have determined the left and right subclass decomposition correctly? The argumentation for the right subclass decomposition would then work analogously?

**a)**

For each $g \in \mathbb{Z}$, $g H=\{g h: h \in H\}=\{g+4 n: n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.
All these classes are equivalent, as the following applies for each $g_{1}, g_{2} \in \mathbb{Z}$: $g_{1} H=g_{2} H$ or $g_{1} \sim g_{2}(\bmod H)4 if and only if $g_{1}-g_{2} \in H$, which means that $g_{1}-g_{2}=$ $4 n$ for a $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

The index $[G: H]$ is the number of different left subclasses and therefore $[G: H]=|\mathbb{Z} / 4 \mathbb{Z}|=4$

**b)**

- $(1) H=\{(1),(12)\}$
- $(12) H=\{(12),(1)\}$
- $(13) H=\{(13),(123)\}$
- $(23) H=\{(23),(132)\}$
- $(123) H=\{(123),(13)\}$
- $(132) H=\{(132),(23)\}$

As all these classes are different and each contain two elements, the index is $[G: H]=\left|\mathscr{S}_{3} / H\right|=6 / 2=3$.

Comment: In the sense, left and right cosets? You have determined only left cosets (subclass decomposition) for the second case. Probably, this exercise might have been given to realize that the left and right decompositions may not be same always for a given subgroup $H$ of a group $G$. This will be realized if the right subclass decomposition is computed for the second case. For the first case, both will be same as the group is abelian. Although your approach is correct, you are encouraged to find the right subclass decomposition for the second example.

Comment: @YathirajSharma: Thanks for your hint! Is this right for the right subclass:
- $(1) H=\{(1),(12)\}$
- $(12) H=\{(12),(1)\}$
- $(13) H=\{(13),(132)\}$
- $(23) H=\{(23),(123)\}$
- $(123) H=\{(123),(23)\}$
- $(132) H=\{(132),(13)\}$

Comment: a) is so correct?
Left subclass decomposition: $g H=\{g+4 n: n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ for all $g \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Right subclass decomposition: $H g=\{4 n+g: n \in \mathbb{Z}\} $ for all $g \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we set left class decomposition of $G$ by $H$ to be $\{gH: g\in G\}$ and right class decomposition of $G$ by $H$ to be $\{Hg:g\in G\}$, then

(a) The left class decompositions of $\mathbb{Z}$ by $\mathbb{4Z}$ are

1. $H_0 = \{4n|n\in \mathbb{Z}\}=0+\mathbb{4Z}$ (Set of all integers leaving remainder $0$ when divided by $4$).
2. $H_1 = \{4n+1| n\in \mathbb{Z}\} = 1+\mathbb{4Z}$ (All integers leaving remainder $1$ when divided by $4$).
3. $H_2 = \{4n+2| n\in \mathbb{Z}\} = 2+\mathbb{4Z}$ (All integers leaving remainder $2$ when divided by $4$).
4. $H_3 = \{4n+3| n\in \mathbb{Z}\} = 3+4\mathbb{Z}$ (All integers leaving remainder $3$ when divided by $4$).

Now, if we take any other integer, say $g$, then the set $g+\mathbb{4Z} = \{g+4n|n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is going to be one of the above sets. Hence the left subclass decompoistion is going to be $\{H_0, H_1, H_2, H_3\}$. Also, since the group $\mathbb{Z}$ is abelian, the right subclass decomposition is going to be the same as that of left.

(b) For the second group, which I presume to be $S_3$ (set of all permutations of 3 symbols under the composition operation), the left subclass decmoposition of $S_3$ by $H$ would be as you have noted down. Coming to the right, there is a change:

$H(1) = \{1, (1\,\,2)\}$

$H(1\,\,2) = \{1, (1\, \, 2)\}$

$H(1\,\,3) = \{(1\,\,3), (1\,\,3\,\,2)\}$

$H(2\,\,3) = \{(2\,\,3), (1\,\,2\,\,3)\}$

$H(1\,\, 2\,\,3) = \{(1\,\,2\,\,3), (2\,\,3)\}$

$H(1\,\, 3\,\, 2) = \{1\,\,3\,\,2), (1\,\,3)\}$

Comment: Thank you for the final visualisation :)